# Google Drive API and Android Studio - Uploading Video File from Android Phone to Users Google Drive

Tags: java, upload, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to develop an app where the user takes a photo and uploads it to Google Drive automatically (The image is not saved on the phone).
 I figured out the code for that thanks to a Google Drive tutorial, but I have no idea how I would do that when it comes to upload videoes?

**Here is the code for photo uploading:**

```
package com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi.DriveContentsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.MetadataChangeSet;

/**
 * Android Drive Quickstart activity. This activity takes a photo and saves it
 * in Google Drive. The user is prompted with a pre-made dialog which allows
 * them to choose the file location.
 */
public class VideoCapture extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "drive-quickstart";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_VIDEO = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Byte mVideoToSave;


/**
 * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
 */

private void saveFileToDrive() {
    // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
    final Byte video = mVideoToSave;
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                    // If the operation was not successful, we cannot do anything
                    // and must
                    // fail.
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                        return;
                    }
                    // Otherwise, we can write our data to the new contents.
                    Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
                    // Get an output stream for the contents.
                    OutputStream outputStream = result.getDriveContents().getOutputStream();
                    // Write the bitmap data from it.
                    ByteArrayOutputStream mBAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] mByte = new byte[1024];
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(mBAOS.toByteArray());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
                    }
                    // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
                    // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
                    MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setMimeType("video/mp4").setTitle("Android Video.mp4").build();
                    // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
                    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                            .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                            .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                            .setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
                            .build(mGoogleApiClient);
                    try {
                        startIntentSenderForResult(
                                intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
        // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
        // failures.
        // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_VIDEO:
            // Called after a photo has been taken.
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Store the image data as a bitmap for writing later.
                mVideoToSave = (Byte) data.getExtras().get("data");
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
            // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Image successfully saved.");
                mVideoToSave = null;
                // Just start the camera again for another photo.
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE),
                        REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_VIDEO);
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, result.getErrorCode(), 0).show();
        return;
    }
    // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
    // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
    // authorization
    // dialog is displayed to the user.
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
    if (mVideoToSave == null) {
        // This activity has no UI of its own. Just start the camera.
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE),
                REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_VIDEO);
        return;
    }
    saveFileToDrive();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}
}
```

Comment: Well, if you check the Drive [docu](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads), you will have 3 options in uploading files. The Simple upload for quick transfer of smaller files (5 MB or less), Multipart upload for quick transfer of smaller files and metadata all in a single request and the Resumable upload for reliable transfer and for larger files. This is a good strategy for most applications, since it also works for smaller files at the cost of one additional HTTP request per upload. For the video type, just use the `mimeType` for video `application/vnd.google-apps.video`.

Comment: But i have no idea how i would put this together into code that would actually work. Especially with the mimeType. And what about the bitmap file? I mean about the byte and compressing and so on.